# Mostrar Numero con formato de moneda correcto

Tags: php

Tengo estos valores:

```
(string) 10.54
(string) 10.5
(string) 10.0
(string) 10.00
(string) 10
(int) 10.54
(int) 10.5
(int) 10.0
(int) 10.00
(int) 10
```

Deseo mostrarlo con el formato 10.00 (moneda peruana) por ejemplo si es:

```
10.5 me muestre 10.50
10 me muestre 10.00
```

se que existe una funcion llamada `money_format();` pero no puedo usarla ya que la version de mi php no cuenta con ello y de momento no instalare la nueva version.

de ante mano gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format)

Como quieres 2 decimales podrías hacer esto:

```
$money = "10";
echo number_format((float)$money, 2, '.', ''); // "10.00"
```

Comment: Excelente esa es la respuesta , se te agradece la ayuda.

Comment: Genial @IntruzO! :)